How to support change password on Keycloak - user federation with DB and LDAP
In my application, the users can be present in the database (the passwords are stored with encryption) as well as in multiple LDAP directories. Currently, we support either database or LDAP authentication.
Now, to support both DB and LDAP authentication, we are exploring Keycloak option.
However, I am not sure how Keycloak can support change password, forgot password and my application's dual factor authentication.
When the user hit my application URL, I am redirecting it to the Keycloak login page. But, how can I still use my application's change password, forgot password and dual factor authentication
